# sql запрос вешает Rails приложение

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

У нас довольно большое Rails приложение, когда средствами ActiveRecord делаю запрос в большую таблицу с миллионами записей, то приложение становится недоступно пользователям до окончания данного запроса, подскажите как этого можно избежать?
В качестве сервера используем thin, БД PostgreSQL, веб-сервер nginx

Comment: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я судя по всему неправильно сформулировал вопрос
Затруднение в том, что в приложении происходит формирование отчетов за большие промежутки времени, данные по ним рассчитываются по запросу из базы данных
В момент формирования отчета, а это занимает в районе 15 минут, приложение становится недоступно другим пользователям

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Вполне нормально, что в больших БД некоторые запросы могут занимать продолжительное время (хотя 15 минут - это многовато). Но если Ваш запрос выполняется синхронно, т.е. прямо из экшена контроллера идет запрос в БД и не возвращается минуты - это уже плохо. Несколько параллельных подобных запросов заставят приложение ответить "отказом в обслуживании (503)".

Решение проблемы - асинхронный запрос. Контроллер получает запрос, запускает напр. [ActiveJob](http://rusrails.ru/active_job_basics) и рендерит ответ. Пользователь условно видит сообщение "Ожидайте, Ваш запрос обрабатывается" и спокойно пользует приложение дальше.

Вот еще пара ссылок:

[Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

[Sidekiq Wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki)

В общем случае, необходимо проектировать приложение таким образом, чтобы запросы обрабатывались секунды (единицы секунд). Если запрос предполагает нечто тяжелое и долгое - лучше реализовать через отложенную задачу.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, думал смотреть как раз в сторону sidekiq, но не был уверен, что это сработает в моем случае и еще раз спасибо за совет!